# Alternative to ant stopwatch task

Tags: ant, time, echo, stopwatch, ant-contrib

I found **ant task** `stopwatch` in *ant-contrib* but I'm missing `echo level` and `duration format` parameters there.
So I need to start **ant in non-quiet mode** to get the `stopwatch elapsed` output (seeing unwanted **ant** `echo` messages in addition):

```
<target name="build">
    <stopwatch name="foo"/>

    <sleep milliseconds="50"/>   <!-- do something -->
    <echo level="info" message="message not wanted to see normally"/>

    <stopwatch name="foo" action="elapsed"/>
</target>
```

Alternatively I only see writing own target or macro like

```
<macrodef name="echo-with-time">
    <attribute name="message" default="" />
    <attribute name="level" default="warning" />
    <sequential>
        <local name="now"/>
        <tstamp><format property="now" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"/> </tstamp>
        <echo level="@{level}" message="[${now}] @{message}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

**Question:** is there a way to **output the duration only** (like calculate with taken time properties)?

Answer (score 0):

You could read in a current timestamp using a self-defined `<scriptdef>` at the start and end of the thing you want to time, and then use the `math` task to calculate the difference.

Something like this:

```
<var name="start" unset="true"/>
<var name="stop" unset="true"/>
<var name="duration" unset="true"/>

<unix-timestamp property="start" />
<!-- Do something to be timed -->
<unix-timestamp property="stop" />
<math result="duration" operand1="${stop}" operation="-" operand2="${start}" datatype="int"/>
<echo message="Task took ${duration} seconds"/>
```

Where `<unix-timestamp>` is a `<scriptdef>` in any supported language

```
<scriptdef name="unix-timestamp" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="property" />
    <![CDATA[
        var property = attributes.get("property");
        var nowSeconds = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
        project.setProperty(property, nowSeconds);
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```